# Actuator - custom logfile endpoint possible?

Tags: spring-boot, logback, spring-boot-actuator

I have set up my log configuration using logback.

The configuration sets up my logs in a rolling manner in a custom location. This means that I'm not using either:

"logging.file" or "logging.path" in my application.yml configuration, and as a consequence, the logfile endpoint no longer works.

Does anybody know of a way to customize this endpoint, so that I can point to the location/file specified in my logback.xml configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the two sections on Logging [26](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html) & [74](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html). It looks like it recommends using the logback-spring.xml config file with the base.xml configuration. With that you can still use the logging.file or logging.path application properties within the configuration. That way the `/logfile` endpoint is still valid for the current log file (probably won't look into the rolling files if that is what you setup).

Comment: Hi Shawn, thanks you pointed me in the right direction - seems to work now.

Comment: This create 2 log file. one  as per the logging.file or logging.path and one as per  logback.xml. is there any way to avoid generating same log in 2 files.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the log file source from which the actuator will read.

To do that, try to use this property in your application.properties

```
endpoints.logfile.external-file=/var/log/app.log
```

or (based on your springboot version):

```
management.endpoint.logfile.external-file=/var/log/app.log
```

Comment: management.endpoint.logfile.external-file works for actuator/logfile endpoint

Answer (score 0):

It is working for me with Springboot 3.1.2

management.endpoint.logfile.external-file=./logs/mylog.log

Then it will show the log file on Springboot admin ui.