# Spring boot Actuator /logfile link is not working after providing custom logback-spring.xml which is configured to attach date in logfile name

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-boot-actuator

I have a Spring Boot project where i recently added `logback-spring.xml` as i wanted my logfile name to have date.

```
eg: application_22-06-2019.log.
```

After i added logback-spring.xml. i got the right logfile name but realised that Actuator's `http://{host}/{port}/logfile` link is not working anymore.

i know that SpringBoot picks the logfile from `${LOG_FILE}` which should be configured using logging.file property.

is there any way i can define something like below in properties file??

```
logging.file=application_${date}.log
```

so that i can remove the logback and logfile link keeps working.

or any other solution with logback??  how to attach date in logfile name using properties file?

Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Actuator - custom logfile endpoint possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39587818/actuator-custom-logfile-endpoint-possible)

Comment: This question is bit different. since i need Today's date attached to my logfile name. i can't pass it from property file using logging.file. If i had to do that,it would be something like: `logging.file=application_${date}.log` and then date has to be resolved accordingly. which is exactly my question. how to resolve date in property file? 2nd approach would be- to use logback.xml and let spring boot know the file name, which is again something i am unaware of. Thanks for your response though @SimonMartinelli